Why is my plot showing slanted temperature and precipitation data?
I am trying to plot temperature and precipitation timeseries over a certain period. When  I print the dataframes (containing the columns date and t/p respectively), the values look alright. But when I plot them, for temperature only a skewed line appears which has nothing to do with the actual data and for precipitation, it also looks weird.
This is the plot I get
Printing the data yields reasonable values:
values for t and p
t_es_1 = filtered_t['es']['period_1']p_es_1 = filtered_p['es']['period_1']

print(t_es_1)print(p_es_1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))  # Set the size of the figuregs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=1, height_ratios=[1,1])  # Make the first subplot taller than the second

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])ax1.plot(t_es_1['date'], t_es_1['t'], label='Temperature', color='blue', marker='o')ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])ax2.plot(p_es_1['date'], p_es_1['p'], label='Precipitation',color='green', marker='o')

ax1.set_ylabel("Temperature (°C)", color='tab:blue')ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:blue')

ax2.set_ylabel("Precipitation (mm)", color='tab:green')ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:green')

plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 0.85, 1])

plt.show()

